# android - how to hide menu in action bar and add to virtual buttons

Tags: android, button, menu, virtual, optionmenu

I want to add menu button in devices with virtual buttons like this :

[image: virtual Menu button]

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely **must** have a menu button on a tablet device (and it's not recommended that you do), then you should set `targetSdkVersion` to "10" or less in the manifest.

Comment: No! I want ActionBar  and menu button in the bottom together :)